# Enable specific dates using bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

It is possible to enable specific dates using bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?
I have tried:

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    language: "en-gb",
    enabledDates: ["2020-11-20, 2020-11-22, 2020-11-25"],
    pickTime: false
});
```

but just only first date `2020-11-20` is enabled.
I have an array of specific dates which I need to enable. Other days must be disabled.

I have stuck here. Maybe it is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enabledDates` take an array of `string`, `Date object` or `moment object`.

> Takes an [ string or Date or moment ] of values and allows the user to select only from those days.

From [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#endisableddates)

So you were close... Just take care about the array structure!

Try this:

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    language: "en-gb",
    enabledDates: ["2020-11-20", "2020-11-22", "2020-11-25"], // Check the quotes!
    pickTime: false
});
```